# How to stop Visual Studio from installing unnecessary dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dependencies

Visual Studio installs too many dependencies, from SQL Data-Tier App Framework to Team Foundations Object Models and sync framework and a bunch of other SDKs that I never chose to install. The custom installation only allows me to choose from the programming languages.
How do I stop visual studio from installing all those dependencies? Are all of them actually necessary?

Comment: You have near total control over what Visual Studio installs.  If something is installed then the configuration choices you made mean Visual Studio requires it.

Comment: not really. in this case, for web development, visual studio would need more then 10 different versions of SQL Server while it should really just need one. Aslo Version Control gets installed automatically without me giving permission.